# Firestore - Get document with ID whose path is unknown - Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm very new to Firebase cloud functions. Pardon me for my naive question.
I have a Firestore Database in this format :

**Collection(Products) => Document(unknownId) => Collection(Cheap) => Document(Soap) => Fields**

My question is how do I get the fields of **Soap** without knowing its complete path.
I have been fiddling around for last 2 days but no luck. I have tried many things but nothing seems to work, and I don't know which code to share here since I tried so many. I read the firebase cloud functions docs but it's more confusing.

```
exports.test = functions
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      cors(req,res, async () => {
        admin.firestore().collectionGroup("Cheap").where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "==","Soap" ).get().then((result) => {
          console.log(result)
          res.status(200).send("Success") 
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('error')
        // }); 
      });
       
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the path you want to look for as a filed inside the document. In your case `documentId(), "==","Soap"`, which is the relative path I'm assuming you need.

Comment: But the problem is I don't know the path of the field.

Comment: when you create the document, save it there

Comment: I'm sorry pal, I'm not getting you. The document is created by admin and the above code is trying to read the doc by client's request. If you can edit my code then it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's not about editing the code. What you need to do is store the path in the document, when the document is created. Then you can query all the documents which satisfy the condition. Same as if you want to get all the documents where the role is student for example.`{"role":"student"}` , you would do `{"path": "Soap"}`.

Answer (score 0):

The document ID field in a collection group query holds the entire path to the document, so your `==` on just the document name won't work in this context.

To allow the query, I'd probably store the value you want to query on in a field in the `Cheap` document too. So that means you'd give the `Soap` document a field `Name: "Soap"` too, and query on that field rather than the document ID.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an answer -

```
exports.test = functions
.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req,res, async () => {
      let query = db.collectionGroup('Cheap')
      let response = []
      await query.get().then((data)=>{
        let docs = data.docs
        docs.map((val)=>{
          if (val.id == "Soap") {
            let Title = val.data().Title
            return response.push(Title)
          }
        })
      })
      return  res.status(200).send(response) 
      })
    })
```

This worked for me, but this won't be an ideal solution if your database is huge. Hopefully that's not the case for me. Thanks ✨